# Taxonomies в WorldPress или ЧПУ

Tags: wordpress, чпу

Всем привет! Два дня мучаюсь с данной проблемой:

Имеется таксономия с таким выводом:

**www.mydomian.ru/escort-cat/brunette/**

Нужно поменять ссылку на такой вид:

**www.mydomian.ru/brunette-escort**

Много перерыл материала, очень много вариантов но никакой не работает. Точнее работает, но не так как нужно, сразу пропадают другие настройки. Нашел данный пункт в таксономии связанный с путями, помогите настроить. Или хотя бы дайте подсказку в какую сторону копать..

настройка ЧПУ таксономии
[image]

Comment: Если же ставлю в поле Replace (см. скрин) слеш , то выводится без escort-cat , но сразу перестают открываться другие ссылки типа /news , /contact и прочее.

Comment: Если же просто убираю галочку с поля Rewrite , то задается url такого вида:

www.mydomian.ru/?escort-cat=brunette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем нагугил как убрать slug посредством вставки кода в function.php, может кому-нибудь в будущем понадобиться, оставляю тут:

```
// смена запроса
 add_filter('request', 'true_smenit_request', 1, 1 );

function true_smenit_request( $query ){
$taxonomia_name = 'escort-cat'; // укажите название таксономии здесь, это также могут быть рубрики category или метки post_tag

// запросы для дочерних элементов будут отличаться, поэтому нам потребуется дополнительная проверка
if( $query['attachment'] ) :
    $dochernia = true; // эту переменную задаём для себя, она нам потребуется дальше
    $urlyarlyk = $query['attachment']; // это ярлык данного термина/рубрики/метки
else:
    $dochernia = false;
    $urlyarlyk = $query['name']; // как видите, здесь ярлык хранится в другой переменной запроса
endif;


$termin = get_term_by('slug', $urlyarlyk, $taxonomia_name); // получаем элемент таксономии по ярлыку

if ( isset( $urlyarlyk ) && $termin && !is_wp_error( $termin )): // если такого элемента не существует, прекращаем выполнение кода

    // для страниц дочерних элементов код немного отличается
    if( $dochernia ) {
        unset( $query['attachment'] );
        $parent = $termin->parent;
        while( $parent ) {
            $parent_term = get_term( $parent, $taxonomia_name);
            $urlyarlyk = $parent_term->slug . '/' . $urlyarlyk; // нам нужно получить полный путь, состоящий из ярлыка текущего элемента и всех его родителей
            $parent = $parent_term->parent;
        }
    } else {
        unset($query['name']);
    }

    switch( $taxonomia_name ): // параметры запроса для рубрик и меток отличаются от других таксономий
        case 'category':{
            $query['category_name'] = $urlyarlyk;
            break;
        }
        case 'post_tag':{
            $query['tag'] = $urlyarlyk;
            break;
        }
        default:{
            $query[$taxonomia_name] = $urlyarlyk;
            break;
        }
    endswitch;

endif;

return $query;

}

// смена самой ссылки
add_filter( 'term_link', 'true_smena_permalink', 10, 3 );

function true_smena_permalink( $url, $term, $taxonomy ){

$taxonomia_name = 'escort-cat'; // название таксономии, тут всё понятно
$taxonomia_slug = 'escort-cat'; // ярлык таксономии - зависит от параметра rewrite, указанного при создании и может отличаться от названия,
// как например таксономия меток это post_tag, а ярлык по умолчанию tag

// выходим из функции, если указанного ярлыка таксономии нет в URL или если название таксономии не соответствует
if ( strpos($url, $taxonomia_slug) === FALSE || $taxonomy != $taxonomia_name ) return $url;

$url = str_replace('/' . $taxonomia_slug, '', $url); // если мы ещё тут, выполняем замену в URL

return $url;
 }

add_action('template_redirect', 'true_delaem_redirect');

 function true_delaem_redirect() {

// указываем здесь свои значения
$taxonomia_name = 'escort-cat';
$taxonomia_slug = 'escort-cat';

// выходим из функции, если ярлыка таксономии нет в URL
if( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $taxonomia_slug ) === FALSE)
    return;

// делаем суперскую проверку, чтобы случайно не редиректнуть страницы, которые не следует
if( ( is_category() && $taxonomia_name=='category' ) || ( is_tag() && $taxonomia_name=='post_tag' ) || is_tax( $taxonomia_name ) ) :

        wp_redirect( site_url( str_replace($taxonomia_slug, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ), 301 ); // сам редирект
    exit();

endif;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте плагин [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/), он как раз для таких задач предназначен.